# Python simple battleship game

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, battleship

I'm relatively new to Python, I decided to make a simple battleship game. Is there anything I should do to make it shorter, or in practice, "better"?

```
from pprint import pprint as pp
import random

Rows = 0
Columns = 0
turns = 0
Answer = "NaN"

print("Welcome to battleship!")

while (Rows > 10) or (Columns > 10) or (Rows <= 0) or (Columns <= 0):
    Rows = int(input("Please enter the number of rows you want. \n"))
    Columns = int(input("Please enter the number of columns you want. \n"))

def create_grid(Rows, Columns):
    #Creates the 2D Data Grid
    grid = []
    for row in range(Rows):
        row = []
        for col in range(Columns):
            row.append(' ')
        grid.append(row)
    return grid

grid = create_grid(Rows,Columns)

def display_grid(grid, Columns):
    #Prints the labels for the grid
    column_names = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'[:Columns]
    print('  | ' + ' | '.join(column_names.upper()) + ' |')
    for number, row in enumerate(grid):
       print(number + 1, '| ' + ' | '.join(row) + ' |')

grid = create_grid(Rows, Columns)
display_grid(grid, Columns)

def random_row(grid):
    #Makes a random row integer
    return random.randint(1,len(grid))

def random_col(grid):
    #Makes a random column integer
    return random.randint(1,len(grid[0]))

def update_gridHit(grid, GuessRow, GuessColumn):
    grid[GuessRow-1][GuessColumn-1] = 'O'

def update_gridMiss(grid, GuessRow, GuessColumn):
    grid[GuessRow-1][GuessColumn-1] = 'X'

ShipRow = random_row(grid)
ShipColumn = random_col(grid)

#Testing purposes only, comment out if needed.
print(ShipRow)
print(ShipColumn)

while (turns != 5):
    GuessRow = int(input("What row do you guess? \n"))
    GuessColumn = int(input("What column do you guess? \n"))

    if (GuessRow == ShipRow) and (GuessColumn == ShipColumn):
        turns += 1
        update_gridHit(grid, GuessRow, GuessColumn)
        display_grid(grid, Columns)
        print("You hit the battleship! Congratulations!")
        break

    else:
        if (GuessRow < 1 or GuessRow > Rows) or (GuessColumn < 1 or GuessColumn > Columns):
            #Warning if the guess is out of the board
            print("Outside the set grid. Please pick a number within it your Rows and Columns.")

        elif (grid[GuessRow-1][GuessColumn-1] == "X"):
            #If "X" is there than print that it missed
            print("You guessed that already.")

        else:
            #Updates the grid with an "X" saying that you missed the ship
            turns += 1
            print("You missed the ship.")
            update_gridMiss(grid, GuessRow, GuessColumn)
            display_grid(grid, Columns)

    if (turns >= 5):
        print("Game over! You ran out of tries")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Variable naming

In general, you should follow PEP8, the Python style guide. In particular, it suggests using lowercase for variable names. That is, `rows` instead of `Rows`.

## User input conditions

```
while (Rows > 10) or (Columns > 10) or (Rows <= 0) or (Columns <= 0):
    Rows = int(input("Please enter the number of rows you want. \n"))
    Columns = int(input("Please enter the number of columns you want. \n"))
```

So, if I enter a correct row, but a wrong column, it'll ask again. Without telling me what I did wrong.

I'd suggest

```
rows = 0
while not (0 < rows <= 10):
    rows = int(input("Please enter the number of rows you want [1-10]."))
```

And a similar loop for columns. This has one problem: What if the user does not enter a number but something else? 'Pizza' or 'one'. In that case, the `int` throws an exception, and that should be handled as well.

```
rows = 0
while not (0 < rows <= 10):
    try:
        rows = int(input("Please enter the number of rows you want [1-10]."))
    except ValueError:
        pass  # Just re-ask the question.
```

## Mixing statements and definitions

The code as given has the form

```
define function
run some statements
define function
run some statements
```

In general, you should use

```
define function
define function
define function
define function main:
    statements
    statements
if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

## Re-using variables

Notice how in `create_grid`, the variable `row` has two purposes: It is both a number (due to the `for row in range(Rows)`), and a list. Please don't do that. Because the number `row` is unused, we should indicate that to the readers by using the conventional `_` as variable name.

```
def create_grid(Rows, Columns):
    #Creates the 2D Data Grid
    grid = []
    for _ in range(Rows):
        row = []
        for _ in range(Columns):
            row.append(' ')
        grid.append(row)
    return grid
```

(Note: I myself prefer using a double underscore `__` instead, but convention is `_`.)

## Encapsulation

Not sure if you are at the level of classes yet, but I'd suggest learning about them.

Instead of

```
def create_grid(Rows, Columns):
    #Creates the 2D Data Grid
    grid = []
    for row in range(Rows):
        row = []
        for col in range(Columns):
            row.append(' ')
        grid.append(row)
    return grid

grid = create_grid(Rows,Columns)
```

You can write

```
class Grid(object):
    def __init__(self, columns, rows):
        self.columns = columns
        self.rows = rows
        self._grid = []
        for __ in range(rows):
            row = []
            for __ in range(columns):
                row.append(' ')
            self._grid.append(row)
```

Now, that last part (assigning `self._grid`) can be done 'nicer' (and faster!).

```
self._grid = [ [' ' for __ in range(columns)] for __ in range(rows)]
```

## Useless call to `.upper`.

In `display_grid`, you've written

```
    column_names = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'[:Columns]
    print('  | ' + ' | '.join(column_names.upper()) + ' |')
```

Why not

```
    column_names = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'[:columns]
    print('  | ' + ' | '.join(column_names) + ' |')
```

That's a bit nicer, right?

## Using `enumerate`

The builtin `enumerate` has a second argument: `start`. You can use it to signal counting should start at `1` instead:

```
    for number, row in enumerate(grid, 1):
       print(number, '| ' + ' | '.join(row) + ' |')
```

## `display_grid` as a method on the class

If you follow my suggestion of turning the grid into a class, you can write

```
def display(self):
    """
    Displays a grid.
    """
    column_names = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'[:self.columns]
    print('  | ' + ' | '.join(column_names) + ' |')
    for number, row in enumerate(self._grid, 1):
       print(number, '| ' + ' | '.join(row) + ' |')
```

But that's just a suggestion.

```
grid = create_grid(Rows, Columns)
display_grid(grid, Columns)
```

## Docstrings

In Python, it is the convention to add the documentation of a method/function in a docstring.

Instead of

```
def random_row(grid):
    #Makes a random row integer
    return random.randint(1,len(grid))
```

write

```
def random_row(grid):
    """
    Makes a random row integer
    """
```

(There are also a lot of conventions on how to phrase a docstring. I won't get into that for now.)

## Parenthesis in conditional

The code says

```
while (turns != 5):
```

It could (and should) be

```
while turns != 5:
```

That is, you don't need the `(` and `)` there.

## Weird order in the guess loop

Now, the following is just preference. But to me, the final loop is unclear. I've written it as pseudo-code below.

The final part looks like this (pseudocode)

```
while (turns != 5):
    get_guess
    if hit:
        turns += 1
        notify_success
        break
    else:
        if out_of_bounds:
            # Print out-of-bounds message
        elif already_guessed:
            # Print already guessed message
        else:
            # Update miss
if (turns >= 5):
    # Print 'you lost'
```

What I notice is that it first checks for hit, before checking if the input is valid (in bounds, and not already guessed).

I'd suggest cleaning it up as follows:

```
while turns != 5:
    while True:
        get_guess()
        if out_of_bounds:
            # Print out-of-bounds message
        elif already_guessed:
            # Print already guessed message
        else:
            break
    turns += 1
    if hit:
        # Update grit hit.
        # Print hit message.
        break
    else:
        # Update grid miss
        # Print miss message.
    display_grid()
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a way that you can reduce the amount of code in `create_grid`.
If you use the `*` operator on a list/string and a number then it duplicates it.
Take the following:

```
>>> 'na ' * 16 + 'Batman'
'na na na na na na na na na na na na na na na na Batman'
>>> [' '] * 5
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
```

This will allow you to remove the entire `for col in range(Columns):` part.
You may think that you could simplify the entire code to say:

```
return [[' '] * columns] * rows
```

But that'll not work as intended.
This is as all the rows will be the same object, and so if you change one, you'll change them all.

```
>>> a = [[' '] * 5] * 5
>>> a
[[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']]
>>> a[0][0] = 'b'
>>> a
[['b', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], ['b', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], ['b', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], ['b', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], ['b', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']]
>>> a[0] is a[1]
True
>>> a[0] == a[1]
True
>>> [' '] is [' ']
False
>>> [' '] == [' ']
True
```

To overcome this, you need to create the outer list manually.
You can do this the way you are currently, or with a comprehension.

Using a [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) here would be better, but could be confusing to learn.

Say we have the list `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, but we want to multiply everything in it by two, to get `[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]` you can do:

```
>>> my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> output_list = []
>>> for i in my_list:
        output_list.append(i * 2)
>>> output_list
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Alternately if you:

1. wrap the for loop in brackets `[]`.
2. Remove the `output_list.append` and `:`.
3. move the `i * 2` to the beginning.

You can make it easier to read.

```
>>> my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> output_list = [i * 2 for i in my_list]
>>> output_list
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

And so this function could be:

```
def create_grid(rows, columns):
    return [[' '] * columns for _ in range(rows)]
```

---

The only other glaring 'issue' Sjoerd didn't go over is how you format the board for print.
Currently you format it as:

```
print(number + 1, '| ' + ' | '.join(row) + ' |')
# Or joining the main chunks:
'{number} | {row} |'
```

Python allows you to use this notation to format output.
So all you need to use is it's [`.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) passing the number and row.

```
'{0} | {1} |'.format(number + 1, ' | '.join(row))
```

I mostly suggest this as from a glance your prints seemed to be one space out.
And so you could change `display_grid` to:

```
import string
def display_grid(grid):
    column_names = string.ascii_uppercase[:len(grid[0])]
    print('{0} | {1} |'.format(' ', ' | '.join(column_names)))
    for number, row in enumerate(grid, 1):
        print('{0} | {1} |'.format(number, ' | '.join(row)))
```

---

As Sjoerd Job Postmus correctly said you should follow [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), and should definitely follow their point on "Mixing statements and definitions".